# How To InsertText At Cursor Position In Wysihtml5-Sandbox Editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, wysihtml5

sandbox editor and have some constants that I want to insert into this iframe. My list of constants is given below:

```
<ul id="email-template-tag" style="margin:0px 0px 5px 0px;padding:0px;">
    <?php foreach($tags as $key=>$value){?>
    <li class="sms-template-tag sms-template-tag" data-value="<?php echo $key;?>"><?php echo $value;?></li>
    <?php }?>
</ul>
```

And the Javascript code is given below:

```
$(document).on('click','#email-template-tag li', function() {
    var caretPos = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow.getSelection();
    var textAreaTxt = $('iframe.wysihtml5-sandbox').contents().find('html body').html();
    var txtToAdd = $(this).attr('data-value');
    $('iframe.wysihtml5-sandbox').contents().find('html body').html(textAreaTxt.substring(0, caretPos) + txtToAdd + textAreaTxt.substring(caretPos) ).focus();
});
```

But the code is not working properly. It always inserts the li data-value at the first position.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [insertHTML](https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5/wiki/Supported-Commands#insertHTML)

> editorInstance.composer.commands.exec("insertHTML", "HTMLToInsert");

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Initialize editor

$(".wysihtml5-sandbox").wysihtml5();

// get Instance

var wysihtml5Editor = $('.wysihtml5-sandbox').data("wysihtml5").editor;

// append you data at cursor position in editor

wysihtml5Editor.composer.commands.exec("insertHTML", "HTMLToInsert");
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.